# Maven Learning Questions

Tags: maven

In eclipse I've installed m2e plugin. I am trying to understand how do you know the names of properties for dependencies to add to pom file?

Say for instance how do you know which artifact id to use?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>                   
</dependency>
```

why here say aspectjrt in artifact id?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and here same as group id ??
is there any pattern?

say my project is missing

```
org.hibernate.Query;
org.hibernate.Session;
org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
```

and in maven dependencies folder I have hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar which effectively contains everything **except** those 3.

Do you write these .pom yourself?

I am betting that for student project I will have to stick with manually adding hundreds of libraries... otherwise I will fail trying to learn it :-)

Comment: I suggest that since you're already using Eclipse, you could save part of your sanity by using the visual `pom.xml` editor, which has a dependency search function :)

Comment: Could you please give more details? Where it will search for dependencies? By default it goes to  .m2 locally , how do I look on the web?

Comment: What dependencies it will search and when depends on the mvn target you invoke. The m2e plugin probably invokes the `compile` target after a pom.xml change, so it'll look for all the dependencies with a `compile` type. Unless you pass the `-o` flag to Maven, it'll look for dependencies first on your local repo, then online. The online repos are defined either on Maven's "global" config file, or the `settings.xml` file at `~/.m2` or the project's `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You know what groupId:artifactId:version (we call these coordinates) to use by which artifact you want. Most often, you find out which artifact you want by reading it in the project's documentation, especially for projects with a large number of artifacts, some of which might contain optional addons.
2. aspectjrt is short for AspectJ RunTime.
3. GroupId and artifactId are defined by the creators of the library in question. There's no universal pattern because there's no one central coordinator. There are some conventions that have evolved, though. Generally, the groupId is at least partly the reversed domain name, like the first part of a Java package name is: org.hibernate, org.apache, org.springframework... The artifactId distinctly identifies the role of that particular artifact in the group it belongs to, like spring-core, spring-tx, spring-jms, etc. You can get an idea of what groupId's and artifactId's look like by [searching Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) for some of the libraries you know.
4. If you're missing org.hibernate.SessionFactory, then you don't have hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final on your classpath. If you have that on your classpath, then you're not missing the SessionFactory class. Those three classes you mentioned are most definitely in that artifact, as you can see from [searching for the class in Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C4%7Cfc%3a%22org.hibernate.SessionFactory%22). If you still doubt, do a `jar -tf hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar` and check out the contents yourself. I promise it has those classes.

Comment: Had also a problem with org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException which didn't react at all, used http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C2%7Cfc%3Aorg.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException . But it just didn't resolve it, for some weird reason also didn't add to maven dependencies. Added manually to maven dependencies, this is a pain I would say!

Comment: I'm not clear at all on what you're saying about ObjectRetrievalFailureException. It's clearly available in org.springframework:spring-orm, multiple different version. I don't understand what you mean by "didn't resolve it" and "didn't add to maven dependencies" or what you mean about it being "a pain" to "[add it] manually to maven dependencies".

Comment: I know I am not very clear, it is because I don't fully understand it. Alright then,  error for that "ObjectRetrieval.. cannot be resolved to a type" This didn't work <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
   <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>

Comment: You told it you depend on the POM: `<type>pom</type>`. You want the jar. Change it to `<type>jar</type>`, or better yet just remove `<type>` completely because `jar` is the default and almost always what you want. A typical dependency only has groupId, artifactId, and version (and `<scope>test</scope>` for test libraries). For 95% or more of your dependencies, you'll only have those 3 (or 4) elements.